# How to reuse completions from PathCompleter in prompt_toolkit

Tags: python, autocomplete, prompt-toolkit

I am creating a REPL tool for my project that (simplified for clarity) either directly executes entered commands or (if a command ".x some/path/to/file" is entered) reads and executes them from file. My question is related to  auto-completing the user input (using prompt_toolkit).

I have something like (minimum executable example):

```
import prompt_toolkit
from prompt_toolkit.completion import Completer, Completion
from prompt_toolkit.document import Document
from prompt_toolkit.contrib.completers import PathCompleter


class CommandCompleter(Completer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.path_completer = PathCompleter()
        self.commands = [".x", "command1", "command2"]

    def get_completions(self, document, complete_event):
        if document.text.startswith(".x "):
            sub_doc = Document(document.text[3:])
            yield from (Completion(cmd.text, -document.cursor_position)
#                                  ????????  ?????????????????????????
                        for cmd
                        in self.path_completer.get_completions(sub_doc, complete_event))
#                                                              ???????
        else:
            yield from (Completion(cmd, -document.cursor_position)
                        for cmd in self.commands
                        if cmd.startswith(document.text))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        other_args = {}
        input = prompt_toolkit.prompt(">>> ", completer=CommandCompleter(), **other_args)
        # Do something with input (omitted)
```

The second if-branch (for commands) works correctly but I don't know how to properly call the `PathCompleter.get_completions()` method and reconstruct the `Completion` objects from its result (where the ???'s are) in the first branch. The trick is that I am using the completion only for a part of the input and various sub-stringing, position calculations etc. did not (yet) lead to the satisfactory behaviour (i.e. offering the paths and constructing the correct input line).

I will definitely go on searching but if anyone knows how to rewrite this, it would be very useful.

Note: `yield from self.path_completer.get_completions(document, complete_event)` would be used if the whole input would be just the path (and this works correctly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the following should fix it:

```
sub_doc = Document(document.text[3:])
yield from (Completion(completion.text, completion.start_position, display=completion.display)
            for completion
            in self.path_completer.get_completions(sub_doc, complete_event))
```

- `completion.text` contains the text that is going to be inserted;
- `completion.start_position` contains the place where the text is going to be inserted, relative to the cursor position (in this particular example we can take the value from the nested completer).
- `completion.display` is the value displayed in the pop-up menu. (In this case, the whole filename, rather than only the inserted string.

Feel free to open a GitHub issue if you have any more questions.